# Regex to check digits other than specified string

Tags: python, regex

Need to check the string has only digits. `any` is the only letter expects to be True

Psuedo Code

```
import re
test = '''123,456'''
bool(re.search('[\d+]', test))
```

Out

```
True
```

Below is one more string expects to True

```
test = '''123,456,any''' #any is the only string expects as True
```

Below are some sample strings which expect to be False

```
test = '''abc,def,43''' #only digits accept
test = '''43,,''' #two #commas which makes illegal
test = '''abc,def,43,$'''#dollar makes illegal
```

Expected out

```
False
```

Comment: are they always separated by commas? this might not even need regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
^(?:\d+|any)(?:,(?:\d+|any))*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7rDIpJ/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:\d+|any)`: Match 1+ digits or text `any`
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `,`: Match a comma
  - (?:\d+|any)`: Match 1+ digits or text`any`
- `)*`: End non-capture group. `*` indicates match 0 or more of this group.
- `$`: End

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non regex solution which instead iterates the list, asserting whether only numbers and the string `any` occur or not:

```
def nonNum(x):
    return int(not(re.match(r'^\d+$', x) or x == "any"))

def listValid(x):
    result = map(nonNum, x.split(','))
    return sum(result) == 0

test1 = "123,456,any"  # valid
test2 = "abc,def,43"   # only digits accept
test3 = "43,," #two"   # commas which makes illegal
test4 = "abc,def,43,$" # dollar makes illegal

print(listValid(test1))
print(listValid(test2))
print(listValid(test3))
print(listValid(test4))
```

This prints:

```
True
False
False
False
```

Comment: return sum(result) == 0: has to change to     return sum(result) == 0